# Keep getting 'TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function' using Ziggy for Vue in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have searched and searched and can't seem to find a solution to my problem.

I have taken the following steps:

```
\\Webpack.mix.js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const path = require('path');
mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            ziggy: path.resolve('vendor/tightenco/ziggy/src/js/route.js'),
        },
    },
});

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        //
    ]);
mix.browserSync('127.0.0.1:8008');
```

And then in my app.js I have

```
\\app.js
require('./bootstrap');



import Vue from 'vue'


// Ziggy start here
import route from 'ziggy';
import { Ziggy } from './ziggy';

Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
        route: (name, params, absolute, config = Ziggy) => route(name, params, absolute, config),
    },
});
// ziggy end here




import VendorLoginForm from './vue/components/vendors/auth/VendorLoginForm'
import VendorRegisterForm from './vue/components/vendors/auth/VendorRegisterForm'
import EditVendorProfile from './vue/components/vendors/profile/EditVendorProfile'

import { ValidationProvider, ValidationObserver, extend } from 'vee-validate/dist/vee-validate.full.esm';



extend("password", {
    message: "{_field_} must be at least 10 characters long, contain one uppercase, one lowercase, and one number.",
    validate: value => {
        const strong_password = new RegExp(
            "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.{10,})"
        ); // regex to check our strong password
        return strong_password.test(value); //Test the regex. Test function returns a true or false value.
    }
});



import './scripts/validators'

Vue.component('ValidationProvider', ValidationProvider);
Vue.component('ValidationObserver', ValidationObserver);
Vue.component('extend', extend);



const app = new Vue({
    el: '#vue-app',
    components: { VendorLoginForm, VendorRegisterForm, EditVendorProfile }
});
```

I have ran the php artisan command to generate the ziggy.js and it seems to be working fine when I Ctrl+click it.

However when I got into my component to try to use route as below

```
  mounted() {
      console.log(this.route('home.page'))
  },
```

I get the error:

```
app.js:51783 TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
    at _classCallCheck (app.js:3612)
    at Route (app.js:3630)
    at VueComponent.route (app.js:3345)
    at VueComponent.mounted (app.cbfbd1ac1b8410f1ce58.hot-update.js:172)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (app.js:51749)
    at callHook (app.js:54109)
    at Object.insert (app.js:53032)
    at invokeInsertHook (app.js:56234)
    at VueComponent.patch [as __patch__] (app.js:56453)
    at VueComponent.Vue._update (app.js:53838)
```

Answer (score 0):

this was a nightmare when I was working with Ziggy at first time but I resolved my issue by
after creating ziggy.js in resources folder `php artisan ziggy:generate`

edit my webpack.mix.js file

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const path = require('path');
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .vue()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            ziggy: path.resolve('vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist'),//Note we point to dist folder
        },
    },
});
```

then in App.js

```
import route from 'ziggy';
import {
    Ziggy
} from './ziggy';

Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
        route: (name, params, absolute) => route(name, params, absolute, Ziggy)
    }
});
```

then you can use route in your components

```
console.log(route("home"));
```